# Clone background color in a swing component

Tags: java, swing, colors, clone

Applying what apparently is the same color, to two JButtons, yields different results:

```
            Color colorA = panel.getBackground();
            btnA.setBackground(colorA);

            Color colorB = new Color(panel.getBackground().getRGB());
            btnB.setBackground(colorB);
```

The result looks like this :

[image]

I am aware of the fact that colorA is a reference to panel.getBackground(), while colrB is a new color object, but both have the same rgb values: 


 color A RGB is 238/238/238

color B RGB is 238/238/238

I don't understand why the two similar buttons show different background color.

Here is a full working code:

```
    public class Test {

        public static void main(String[] args)  {

            JFrame jf = new JFrame("Why are the colors different ?");
            jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            jf.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            jf.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,100));
            Dimension size = new Dimension(125, 25);

            JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,15, 15));
            jf.getContentPane().add(panel);

            JButton btnA = new JButton("A");
            btnA.setPreferredSize(size);
            panel.add(btnA);

            JButton btnB = new JButton("B");
            btnB.setPreferredSize(size);
            panel.add(btnB);

            //-- apply background color to buttons
            Color colorA = panel.getBackground();
            btnA.setBackground(colorA);
            Color colorB = new Color(colorA.getRGB());
            btnB.setBackground(colorB);

            jf.validate();
            jf.pack();
            jf.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two is that the color returned by `panel.getBackground()` is an instance of [`javax.swing.plaf.ColorUIResource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/ColorUIResource.html), a subclass of `Color` which implements `UIResource`. This is a special class which is used to handle the look and feel in Java, and isn't treated like a regular color.

In fact, it doesn't matter what the values of the `ColorUIResource` are; any rgb values get rendered the same way, as determined by the look and feel, which will override the color with it's own custom rendering.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand

Comment: `System.out.println(colorA.getClass());` returns `java.awt.Color` and `colorA instanceof ColorUIResource` returns `false`

Answer (score 1):

**The default background is actually a `ColorUIResource` object.**

Change your button back with this:

```
button.setBackground(new ColorUIResource(Color.BLACK));
```

The color you specify doesn't matter.  The `ColorUIResource` object will use the current look and feel.  By default this is set to produce the gradient effect you see.

Comment: :Thanks for the response. Adding  btnB.setBackground(new ColorUIResource(Color.BLACK)); will indded make btnB look like btnA. My question was why  they look different and not how to "fix" it. It is not that btnA is ok and btnB is wrong.

Comment: But I told you.  The ColorUIResource object will use the look and feel specified in the Java Runtime.  This is controlled elsewhere and configured by default to be the gradient effect.  They look different because btnB is set to a solid background color instead.